# FPS stabilization iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have, most of the time, 50+ FPS, but when I load resources(background tread) it drops to 30 FPS. I want to have constant FPS, 30 or even 20, it's not a problem for me. What is the best way to make FPS constant?

Comment: hi. can you provide us with more information? are you using a game engine or some other framework? do you have some sort of mainloop?

Comment: I have my engine, I can change code. I also have a main loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using time-based redrawing, instead of frame based drawing. [Michael Daley](http://www.71squared.com/)'s [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321699424) has some excellent info on this.

Also, try loading as many of your resources as possible in a spritesheet.

Comment: I already use display links(or timer, depending of platform). I load my resources asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if there is an established method, but frame rate in this case is the frequency at which you redraw. 20 FPS is a 50 millisecond redraw rate. One method would be to only redraw if the time between the last redraw and now is >=50 ms.

Comment: I did this on windows version for my game and it's inaccurate. The FPS varies with 1-2 frames